# adding fake_useragent to people_also_ask module

Tags: python, user-agent

I want to scrape google *'people also ask questions/answer'*. I am doing it successfully with the following module.

```
pip install people_also_ask
```

The problem is the library is configured such that no one can send many requests to google. I want to send 1000 requests per day and to achieve that I have to add fake_useragent to module. I tried a lot but when I try to add fake user agent to header it gives error. I am not a pro so I must have done wrong myself. Can anyone help me add fake_useragent to module(people_also_ask). here is working code to get question/answer.

```
from encodings import utf_8
import people_also_ask as paa
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
while True:

    input("Please make sure the queries are in \\query.txt file.\npress Enter to continue...")
    try:
        query_file = open("query.txt","r")
        queries = query_file.readlines()
        query_file.close()
        break
    except:
        print("Error with the query.txt file...")


for query in queries:

    res_file = open("result.csv","a",encoding="utf_8")

    try:
        query = query.replace("\n","")
    except:
        pass

    print(f'Searching for "{query}"')
    
    questions = paa.get_related_questions(query, 14)
    questions.insert(0,query)

    print("\n________________________\n")
    main_q = True
    for i in questions:

        i = i.split('?')[0]
        
        try:
            answer = str(paa.get_answer(i)['response'])
            if answer[-1].isdigit():
                answer = answer[:-11]
            print(f"Question:{i}?")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        print(f"Answer:{answer}")


        if main_q:
            a = ""
            b = ""
            main_q = False
            
        else:
            a = "<h2>"
            b = "</h2>"

        res_file.writelines(str(f'{a}{i}?{b},"<p>{answer}</p>",'))

        print("______________________")

    print("______________________")
    res_file.writelines("\n")

    res_file.close()

print("\nSearch Complete.")
input("Press any key to Exit!")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if 1000 requests a day would be a problem but the rate limit is likely to prevent google from blocking you. You probably need to do more than you're considering to make this work and you may very well be violating google's terms of service already let alone if you do this.

Comment: I have tested sending requests to google with 1 sec gap It takes almost 230 requests and captcha starts blocking requests. With fake user agent I managed to get 1000 requests without any captcha. Only 20 requests were successful without time gap

Comment: What is likely happening is that google's servers are using the user agent string to identify different people NATed to the same ip address. So you are likely tricking their servers into allowing you more requests than they want to give you. This is likely a terms of service violation. If you are doing this to make money you may end up getting sued (I'm not a lawyer this is not legal advice.) If you are doing this for some other reason you really don't have much of a reason to keep doing it and you are unlikely to get someone online to explain to you how to circumvent google's terms of service

Comment: To make it clear first I had a project that I have completed. I will share the code here. What I want to know is why I can not use fake user agent in this library? How It prevents me to use fakeuseragent

Comment: Well most likely the people who made the library specifically didn't want people to violate google's terms of service. It's probably a very easy problem to solve to be honest but as I said given the nature of your question I doubt anyone is going to respond with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is against Google's terms of service, and the wishes of the `people_also_ask` package. This answer is for educational purposes only.

You asked **why** `fake_useragent` is prevented from working. It's not prevented from working, but the `people_also_ask` package simply isn't implementing any calls to make use of any `fake_useragent` methods. You can't just import a package and expect another package to start using it. You manually have to make packages work together.

To do that, you have to have some idea of how the 2 packages work. Have a look at [the source code](https://github.com/lagranges/people_also_ask/blob/master/people_also_ask/google.py) and you will see you can make them work together very easily. Just substitute the constant header in `people_also_ask` with one generated by `fake_useragent` before you request any data.

```
paa.google.HEADERS = {'User-Agent': ua.random} # replace the HEADER with a randomised HEADER from fake_useragent
questions = paa.get_related_questions(query, 14)
```

and

```
paa.google.HEADERS = {'User-Agent': ua.random} # replace the HEADER with a randomised HEADER from fake_useragent
answer = str(paa.get_answer(i)['response'])
```

NOTE:
Not all user agents will work. Google doesn't give related questions depending on the user agent. It is not the fault of either the `fake_useragent`, or the `people_also_ask package`.

Example of the most used browsers only (despite all the user agent strings should now be up to date):

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent(min_percentage=1.3)
ua.random
```

Comment: I have tried this many times. It does not give any error but also dont give results. But I did it directly in package not by importing it. I will test this and respond. Again I am asking this for educational purpose I have solved it with another method

Comment: Not all user agents will work. Google doesn't give related questions depending on the user agent. It is not the fault of either the `fake_useragent`, or the `people_also_ask` package. In order to alleviate the issue somewhat, make sure you call `ua.update()` and you can also use PR #122 of fake_useragents to only select a subset of the newest user agents which are more likely to work, though you will still get a few missed queries. There is a reason the `people_also_ask` package didn't bypass or work-around this limitation from google

Comment: Add this comment to answer as this is the real answer. I will accept the answer after that

Comment: Added to the post, thanks

Comment: bounty is yours.
For information: 
         The same case applies to amazon and ebay

Comment: As the maintainer of `fake-useragent` you don't need to execute `ua.update()` anymore. I updated the browser list, containing more up to date strings. And the data is stored locally within the package itself.